# In jupyter notebook the kernel dies immediately

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just started jupyter notebook and the the kernel just died, the errors were

```
   [I 18:14:40.316 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\brick
[I 18:14:40.316 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 18:14:40.316 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=da23fdd55f08aadd32334cf72b57034f19637b3016b93520
[I 18:14:40.316 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:14:40.332 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=da23fdd55f08aadd32334cf72b57034f19637b3016b93520
[I 18:14:41.346 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 18:14:50.920 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 18:14:54.477 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c867db6f-d2a4-4ddb-9c25-d811e1f2d532
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[I 18:14:57.297 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[I 18:15:00.340 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[I 18:15:03.359 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[W 18:15:04.589 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from c867db6f-d2a4-4ddb-9c25-d811e1f2d532
[I 18:15:06.378 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel c867db6f-d2a4-4ddb-9c25-d811e1f2d532 restarted
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[W 18:15:09.406 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 18:15:09.406 NotebookApp] Kernel c867db6f-d2a4-4ddb-9c25-d811e1f2d532 died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel c867db6f-d2a4-4ddb-9c25-d811e1f2d532 restarted failed!
[W 18:15:09.468 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 18:15:09.472 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/4c861646-dd4c-45f9-9863-7ec1f4dec185 (::1) 7.99ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled4.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 18:16:54.961 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled4.ipynb
[I 21:29:10.617 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[I 21:29:13.230 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[I 21:29:16.263 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[I 21:29:19.295 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[W 21:29:21.159 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891
[I 21:29:22.312 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891 restarted
[E 21:29:22.317 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart callback <bound method ZMQChannelsHandler.on_kernel_restarted of ZMQChannelsHandler(64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891)> failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\restarter.py", line 81, in _fire_callbacks
        callback()
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 435, in on_kernel_restarted
        self._send_status_message('restarting')
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 431, in _send_status_message
        self.write_message(json.dumps(msg, default=date_default))
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 249, in write_message
        raise WebSocketClosedError()
    tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: bad magic number in 'collections': b'\x16\r\r\n'
[W 21:29:25.552 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 21:29:25.552 NotebookApp] Kernel 64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891 died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891 restarted failed!
[E 21:29:25.567 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: dead callback <bound method ZMQChannelsHandler.on_restart_failed of ZMQChannelsHandler(64d63304-b152-4869-8cff-92612086b891)> failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\restarter.py", line 81, in _fire_callbacks
        callback()
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 439, in on_restart_failed
        self._send_status_message('dead')
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 431, in _send_status_message
        self.write_message(json.dumps(msg, default=date_default))
      File "C:\Users\brick\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 249, in write_message
        raise WebSocketClosedError()
    tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
[I 23:11:45.347 NotebookApp] Interrupted...
[I 23:11:45.394 NotebookApp] Shutting down kernels
```

I am using python 3.6.1, and used Miniconda3 to acquire jupyter notebook please help me the kernel also failed to restart.
Thanks!

I hope this will finally help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bad magic number" `b'\x16\r\r\n'` is used in `.pyc` files up to Python 3.5.2. Python [broke the world](https://bugs.python.org/issue29514) when the magic number got updated to `\x17` recently. This may be unrelated to your problem, but my guess is that your interpreter is >= 3.5.3 and your IPython kernel is <= 3.5.2, trying to use the same module-path.

The cause of this error are `.pyc` files, cached python modules "compiled" by a previous version of Python on your computer, that the interpreter IPython is now using can't unpickle.

The solution is to re-install everything, that is, getting a matching interpreter and IPython. You might get away with simply deleting all `.pyc` files; they are regenerated automatically.

Comment: So what I do is get rid of Python 3.6.1 and get python version 3.5.2?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'd suggest you get rid of both the miniconda3 and the ipython installation and use your Python36's `pip3` to install `ipython-notebook` instead.